# Output of a command within here-document

Tags: linux, bash, cat, heredoc

I have a script which contains the code block:

```
cat << EOF > new_script.sh
...
echo "$(pwd)" >> log.txt
...
EOF
```

The script new_script.sh is set to run at a later time. Bash recognizes the $(pwd) within the script and evaluates it before it looks at the entire EOF block, so the pwd of the current directory is output instead of the pwd of new_script.sh when it is run. Why is this the case (what logic does bash use to know to evaluate $(command)) and what is the best solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding an escape $, `\$` , you can solve this issue.

```
cat << EOF > new_script.sh
...
echo "\$(pwd)" >> log.txt
...
EOF
```

Comment: This is probably best for me since it allows other variables to be dereferenced within the heredoc by $.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you put single quotes around the `EOF` marker, the contents of the here-doc are treated like a double-quoted string, so all variables and command substitutions are expanded immediately.

To leave them as literals, use

```
cat << 'EOF' > new_script.sh
...
echo "$(pwd)" >> log.txt
...
EOF
```